# PDF - Aspect Ratio and Sizing

Tags: php, pdf, imagemagick, pdf-generation, ghostscript

Related cross-post:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22296340/convert-pdf-to-editable-web-form

I'm going to be converting PDFs into a series of images (using ImageMagick and GhostScript) for storage and use in a digital forms application. My question relates to PDF sizing:

Are all PDFs the same "physical" size in terms of aspect ratio? Is there a standardised format, similar to something like A4 paper?

I wish to convert all PDFs into the same "size" (maintaining the same aspect ratio) so that I can better develop responsive design.

Comment: Each page of each pdf document can have its individual size which can have an arbitrary aspect ratio.

Comment: It's purely anecdotal, but most PDFs I've come across seem to be in a similar aspect ratio to that of an A4 page. Presumably this is because a lot of them would have been generated from a Microsoft Word document perhaps?

Comment: Yes, pdf files most often represent papers which most often are A4 or Letter sized.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mkl correctly says, there is no standard size for a PDF page, it can be anything from 1 point (1/72 inch) square upwards and can be any aspect ratio. It is common for pages to be Letter or A4 but this is by no mean guaranteed and even in the common sizes the pages may be landscape or portrait.

With Ghostscript, when rendering you can specify a fixed media size (-dFIXEDMEDIA or -gx) and then use -dPDFFitPage which will fit the requested MediaBox of the individual pages to the specified fixed media size, maintaining the aspect ratio.

Note that this may leave areas of the fixed size unmarked (they will appear as white using most file formats, transparent if rendering to PNG). If you want the rendered bitmap to have the same aspect ratio in its physical dimensions as the original PDF file's aspect ratio, that's much harder and requires a degree of PostScript programming. Other tools (eg MuPDF) might be better suited for this task.

Comment: Excellent. Very clear and thorough answer. Thank you